# Dealing with CORS Error When Making a POST Request to an API with an Access Code

Tags: javascript, post

I was supposed to make a POST call from the data I'll get from my form, Here is my code.

```
bookingForm.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
        name,
        email,
        comments
    } = bookingForm.elements;
    const formData = {
        firstname: name.value,
        email: email.value,
        message: comments.value
    };
    console.log(formData);
    const response = await fetch(
        "https://forms.maakeetoo.com/formapi",
        {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
            }
        }
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
});
```

And was supposed to use https://forms.maakeetoo.com/formapi/32 API, and it have some short of Access code as well. But it's also mentioned that *Make a GET request to be same endpoint. Include the access code in the HTTP request header named as CODE*
*curl --header  "Code: <access_code>"*  
Now I'm getting this error while POSTing
`Access to fetch at 'https://forms.maakeetoo.com/formapi' from origin 'http://15.206.68.78:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
`Access to fetch at 'https://forms.maakeetoo.com/formapi' from origin 'http://15.206.68.78:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

````
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:79:28)```
this is my line 79 `const response = await fetch`

What should I do now?
````

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar — `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header. It would be stupid if the JS could give itself permission to read the data.

Comment: The **only** solution to CORS restrictions is to use your own server to make the request on your web pages behalf